# effectComposer in R3F works only in old version but not newest version of R3F

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I was learning how to make these shader kind of animations inside R3F and I saw an effect in codesandbox that I wanted to try but it doesn't work , I realized that I have to install old version of react-three/fiber to be able to work but I am using react v18.2 and this effect can only be work in react v17.0 with react-three/fiber v7.0.6 , how can I edit to be able to work with the latest version , here is the codesandbox and the code that I want to update to the new version

```
import * as THREE from 'three'
import React, { useRef, useMemo, useEffect } from 'react'
import { extend, useThree, useFrame } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { EffectComposer } from 'three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/EffectComposer'
import { ShaderPass } from 'three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/ShaderPass'
import { RenderPass } from 'three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/RenderPass'
import { UnrealBloomPass } from 'three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/UnrealBloomPass'
import { FilmPass } from 'three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/FilmPass'
import { WaterPass } from './post/Waterpass'

extend({ EffectComposer, ShaderPass, RenderPass, WaterPass, UnrealBloomPass, FilmPass })

export default function Effects() {
  const composer = useRef()
  const { scene, gl, size, camera } = useThree()
  const aspect = useMemo(() => new THREE.Vector2(512, 512), [])
  useEffect(() => void composer.current.setSize(size.width, size.height), [size])
  useFrame(() => composer.current.render(), 1)
  return (
    <effectComposer ref={composer} args={[gl]}>
      <renderPass attachArray="passes" scene={scene} camera={camera} />
      <waterPass attachArray="passes" factor={1.5} />
      <unrealBloomPass attachArray="passes" args={[aspect, 2, 1, 0]} />
    </effectComposer>
  )
}
```

How can I edit this code to be able to work with React v18.2 & react-three/fiber latest version?

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.**"*

Comment: Links to external resources may break or the content may change. You must add the code to the question, not a link to an external resource. See [Feedback requested: Runnable code snippets in questions and answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Comment: okay ,i am so sorry i edited the post